# Correct form to tell and write the degrees I hold

Tags: masters, career-path, bachelor, curriculum, italy

If I have a bachelor degree in Physics, how should I write it in a CV? 
What is the correct form between the two:

1. Bachelor of Physics
   or
2. Bachelor in Physics?

The same thing goes for the master degree, right now I have written master of science in physics of materials, is this correct or should be better to just write master in  physics of materials?

Comment: What do your diploma certificate and your university transcript say?

Comment: Most likely, nobody cares.

Comment: What country? The vast vast majority of degrees in the US are Bachelor's of Arts in X, Bachelor's of Science in X, and perhaps Bachelors of Engineering.

Comment: @ThomassupportsMonica I have it in Italian, which is my county and says the title in Italian, like Laurea triennale in fisica

Comment: I added the Italy tag. Hopefully that will summon Massimo

Comment: @AzorAhai but what difference does it make? It's a statement in english, there should be a correct way to say it, regardless of my nationality.

Comment: Because in US English, degrees are usually "Bachelor's of <broad field> in <subfield>." I am not as familiar with UK versions of degrees, and since your degree is named in Italian, there may be a best way to translate it I'm not familiar with. A BA in math and a BS in math imply different coursework, so I'll leave it up to someone familiar with the Italian system to answer

Comment: @AzorAhai thank you for clarification

Comment: I certainly hope that @user111388 is right and nobody cares, because my C.V. just says "B.S. (Physics)" and "Ph.D. (Mathematics)" (with the universities and dates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is for formal use then state it exactly as it appears from your university and give any translation that is logically correct. *But BS in Physics* or *BSc (Physics)* or *Bachelor of Science (Physics)* or similar would all be universally recognized in the English speaking world.

For informal usage (i.e. no legal implications whatever) then either of your suggestions would be fine or something such as I wrote above.

For extremely formal situations, use what the university uses and let the reader translate it. Probably name the university, as well.

Answer (score 3):

As [Buffy's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/144054/20058) says, *BSc in Physics*, or its variants, are OK.

However, if you want to have an official English equivalence of your title, ask to the student's office the [Diploma Supplement](https://ec.europa.eu/education/diploma-supplement_en), which is a bilingual document (Italian and English) aimed at better describing your academic qualifications in an international context, explaining also some details of the local educational system.

For instance, for a master's degree in engineering (sorry, I don't have one for a bachelor's), a diploma supplement from my university reports:

> Master's of science—level of the Bologna process in Electronic
>   Engineering

Answer (score 1):

None of my first three (UK) degrees formally name the subject at all: Bachelor of Arts, Master of Science, Master of Arts. And in due course, I hope, my Doctor of Philosophy degree will be similarly silent (and I think it should be: why should research degrees be shoehorned into some librarian's classification system?).

You just have to explain in your CV what is was you actually studied.

Comment: Note that in some countries applications _require_ to specify the subject. For instance, we have positions for MSc's in Physics or Electronic Engineering, but not Mechanical Engineering. Those with a degree not falling within a certain class would be automatically excluded.

Comment: In my day as an undergraduate at Cambridge degrees were not necessarily awarded in particular subjects. One obtained a degree by passing two Parts of the University examinations, but there was no requirement for those two parts to be in the same, or even in related subjects. Almost everyone did in fact follow the same subject for all three years, but it was quite possible to  mix and match one's own degree, Part I mathematics followed by Part II law was quite feasible.